# Check file permissions

Tags: php, file-permissions

How can I check `file permissions`, without having to run operating system specific command via `passthru()` or `exec()`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [fileperms()](http://php.net/fileperms) function

```
clearstatcache();
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/etc/passwd')), -4);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [is_readable()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php), [is_executable()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-executable.php) etc.. commands.

Comment: Be aware that is_writable() does not check group membership (as of PHP 5.5.18).

Answer (score 7):

Real coders use bitwise operations, not strings ;) This is much more elegant way of handling permissions:

```
function checkPerms($path)
{
    clearstatcache(null, $path);
    return decoct( fileperms($path) & 0777 );
}
```

Comment: What does this return, true/false?

Comment: @S.. it returns permissions as string. For example "644".

Comment: This answer could be more helpful if it explained why this combination of techniques is most appropriate.  There is a missed chance to educate readers here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [fileperms()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) function and substring:

```
substr(decoct(fileperms(__DIR__)), -4); // 0777
substr(decoct(fileperms(__DIR__)), -3); // 777
```

For file:

```
substr(decoct(fileperms(__FILE__)), -4); // 0644
substr(decoct(fileperms(__FILE__)), -3); // 644
```

Replace `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` with your path or variable

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do by checking file permissions?

When writing secure code, it's almost always incorrect to "check, then do" anything.  The reason is that between the checking whether you can do something and actually doing it, the state of the system could change such that doing it would have a different result.

For example, if you check whether a file exists before writing one, don't check whether you wrote the file successfully (or don't check in a detailed-enough fashion), and then later depend on the contents of the file you wrote, you could actually be reading a file written by an attacker.

So instead of checking file permissions, just do whatever it was you were going to do if the permissions check succeeded, and handle errors gracefully.

Comment: There are always feasible reasons for checking permissions, perhaps he's building a daemon for fixing permissions, which doesn't rely on his script to read or write to the files as a different process is going to do that.

Comment: Another example is a rewriteMap program which acts as a gate based on certain file permissions.

Comment: Your answer is very old, so I don't know if virtual filesystems for unit testing even existed back in 2008. That being said, one viable reason for checking file permissions is to verify (in PHPUnit unit test) that the file in your code is assigned proper permissions, when using `vfsStream`. (This use case got me to this page.)

Answer (score 0):

`decoct(fileperms($dir) & 0777)` to get file permission.
Example: var_dump(decoct(fileperms($dir) & 0777)); //return is '755'