# How to check file/directory permission with Zend

Tags: php, file-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466/check-file-permissions)

How to check directory/file permission using zend framework. I would like to know one of my directory have 777 permission.

Thanks

Comment: Afaik ZF has no component that can check for File Permissions. You could write a custom `Zend_Validate_File_Permissions` to do that.

Comment: You don't need Zend Framework for that

Answer (score 2):

[fileperms](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php)

try with this function