# Check to determine if userA has access to fileB (PHP)

Tags: php, permissions

PHP has a [is_readable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) function which checks to see if the file is readable by the owner of the script. Is there a corresponding script to see if a file is readable by a specified user, for example

```
is_readable('Gavrilo Princip', 'black_hand.srj')
```

Comment: None that I'm aware of. You'll need to save the permissions in a database and read from that. (I may be wrong, that's why I didn't post as an answer)

Comment: Check this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466/check-file-permissionsj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962289/chris) and [AndrewR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707247/andrewr) I have come up with a, as of yet untested, solution. This solution is implemented in shell, and waits for input from standard in (designed to work with Apache RewriteMap). However, it can easily be modified to be called from either the command line or from a PHP script. It is a little bit more complicated than it has to be because we are piping the input of a function (`getfacl`) to a `while` loop. When we do this, it starts a new suprocess, so any variables declared or updated inside this loop (ie. `result`) will not be available to the outside world. Furthermore, I used `getfacl` as I can later expand it to also work with ACL permissions as well. Finally, for implementation reasons, I already know the owner of the file (`user`) before calling this script, however, if this is not the case, one can easily find this from the `getfacl` command.

```
#!/bin/bash

#USAGE: STDIN viewer:user:file

while read line
do
   viewer=`echo $4 | cut -d ':' -f 1`
   user=`echo $4 | cut -d ':' -f 2`
   file=`echo $4 | cut -d ':' -f 3`

   result=$(
      getfacl $file 2>/dev/null | while read line
      do
         if [[ $user == $viewer ]] && [[ $line =~ ^user: ]]
         then
            permissions=`echo $line | cut -d ':' -f 3`
            if [[ $permissions =~ r ]]
            then
               echo true
               break
            fi
         elif [[ $user == $viewer ]] && [ $line =~ ^group: ]]
         then
            #NOTE: I take advantage of the fact that each user has one single group and that group has the same name as the user's name
            permissions=`echo $line | cut -d ':' -f 3`
            if [[ $permissions =~ r ]]
            then
               echo true
               break
            fi
         elif [[ $line =~ ^other: ]]
         then
            permissions=`echo $line | cut -d ':' -f 3`
            if [[ $permissions =~ r ]]
            then
               echo true
               break
            fi
         fi
      done
   )

   if [[ $result == "true" ]]
   then
      echo true
   else
      echo false
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Not built in. I don't even think there is a command line utility to check if a certain user has read permissions to a file.

You can write your own function to do the checking though. Look into the [fileperms()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php), [fileowner()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileowner.php), [filegroup()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filegroup.php), and [posix_getpwuid()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwuid.php) functions.

Comment: Yes, I figure I have to run several if conditions on all three owner, group and others, then possibly check `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 1):

Check this question
[Check file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466/check-file-permissions)

PHP fileperms http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php

PHP stat http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php

The examples in there are for *nix systems. I don't know if it will operate the same on Windows hosts.  With these you could get the GID and UID of the file.

I don't know if there is a PHP equivalent that would let you get the UID and/or GID of the particular system user. You may need to get that manually and search against those values. You can find the value typically in the /etc/passwd file

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am only interested in *nix systems. Thanks

Comment: @puk Yea, there are ways to do this using `exec()`, but don't. `exec()` is too much of a security risk. If you have access to create users, then you have access to find their UID and GID.

Comment: are you sure you need access to create users? pretty much anyone can read the file permissions (provided they have read access on the parent directory) and then you check to see if userA is the owner, or is in the group or the file is readable by all.

Comment: I know this wasn't in my original question, but do you know if something like is_readable would take ACLs into consideration? http://beginlinux.com/server_training/server-managment-topics/1038-ubuntu-804-access-control-lists

Comment: @puk What I was saying is that the php functions will give you the file owner's UID and the file's GID, but no way to tie those to a specific username. So you need to be able to access the /etc/passwd file to say "UserA"'s UID is 1000 and belongs to GID 1002.  My assumption was that, if you had these different system users, then you were able to create them and hence that you would have access to /etc/passwd

Comment: @puk In regards to the ACLs. From what I gather, that's an Ubuntu specific package. If your application requires that you are able to work closely between PHP and the system's user security, you may want to look for a solution that includes a PEAR extension.  I haven't done any research myself, but I would start by looking for an ACL package that already had some PHP support.  Or possibly start a new question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9198/discussion-between-puk-and-chris)