# Cannot write to a file using php

Tags: php, permissions, file-get-contents

I've seen similiar questions but the answers did not help me. I'm using the code below. I have checked, the file is being read and it will output the number in count.txt on the page. $hit_count is indeed being incremented (I echoed that for a test). `count.txt` has permissions `777` and `count.txt` is in the same directory as the page I want the data to appear on. I have no idea what to do next. It's incredibly simple code and I have searched for an answer for hours.

```
<?php
$hit_count = @file_get_contents('count.txt'); // read the hit count from file
echo "Site visits since Jun 30,2012: ";
echo $hit_count; //  display the hit count
$hit_count++; // increment the hit count by 1
@file_put_contents('count.txt',  $hit_count); // store the new hit count
?>
```

If I remove the `@` sign to test the error I get the following:

> Warning: file_put_contents(count.txt) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\Hosting\9541237\html\indexTEST.php on line 220

What permissions? `count.txt` is `777`.

Comment: Don't use `@` to suppress errors; they exist for a reason. Instead, write code that doesn't generate errors.

Comment: count.txt is in the same folder as your .php file ?

Comment: The warning is clear: you don't have permission to write. So, check again file permissions (I'd be very surprised if it really had 777 on Windows).

Comment: The folder also needs to have execute permissions, otherwise you can't list any files in the folder so PHP doesn't know where `count.txt` begins on disk.

Comment: I know it seems clear enough I have rwx on public, global and private - sorry I use 777 to mean the same thing.

Comment: and yes count.txt is in the same directory as the php file.

Comment: just double checked that directory containing the php file and the count.txt file have RWX for owner, group and public

Comment: thank u to everyone turns out my hosting service was not actually changing the permission on my file or my directory. Figures.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see what php thinks your file permissions are using `fileperms`.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466/check-file-permissions) question for more info.