# Laravel: create an upload directory on the fly

Tags: laravel

I have got this,

```
$destinationPath = public_path(). '/img/'. $username;
```

which I thought would create the directory alright, but it came up with a

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ File \ Exception \ FileException

Unable to create the "/img/alvarito" directory
```

Any idea what is wrong? seems to me that it is trying to create also the /img/, which already exists, what I naturally want is that inside that 'img' directory creates me subdirectories for each user as they upload their files.

thanks a lot

A

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```php
$destinationPath = public_path(). '/img/'. $username;

if(!file_exists($destinationPath)) File::makeDirectory($destinationPath);
```

This will create the directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answering, I got this reply:

mkdir(): No such file or directory

Comment: Could it be a matter of permissions? I am using a dedicated server, how do I check that permissions thing?

Comment: It could be permission related problem, [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466/check-file-permissions).

Comment: I have directly looked through Filezilla, directory img has 0755, does that mean, 7 = can read anything, 5 can read and execute but not write? is that the reason? But that is a public directory I would not want non-registered people to write in a directory. However, I was told, images are saved in a Public directory.

Comment: Yes, `7 = 4+2+1 (read/write/execute)
6 = 4+2 (read/write)
5 = 4+1 (read/execute)
4 = 4 (read)
3 = 2+1 (write/execute)
2 = 2 (write)
1 = 1 (execute)`

Comment: but then, would anyone, visitor be able to write into that directory? if yes, then why having a public directory? If it stays 0755 it will not let me create a directory, if I change permission, non registered visitors will be able to write files in that directory too?

Comment: How a visitor will write in that directory ?